# Yii Render a Model View Inside CJuiDialog

Tags: php, yii, cjuidialog

I want to render a Model view completely in the CJuiDialog box.

what i did is i have a model JOB for this i have view files that are generated by Gii.

what i want- when clicking on id for each record on index.php i should open CJuiDialog box instead of rendering view file.

But, something going wrong-- when index page is accessed it displays all records for the job model and a pop up CJuiDialog box displaying first record( id=1 record)

and it displaying view for remaining records on the index page.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $this->breadcrumbs=array(
 'Jobs',
);

$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'Create Jobs','url'=>array('create')),
array('label'=>'Manage Jobs','url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>Jobs</h1>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

**_view.php**

```
<?php 
   $target = 'window.location='."'".$this->createUrl('jobs/index')."'";
 $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
  'id'=>'mydialog',
 // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
  'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'View Job..',
    'autoOpen'=>true,
  'buttons' => array(
array('text'=>'Route','click'=> 'js:function(){'.$target.'}'),
array('text'=>'Cancel','click'=> 'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}'),
),
  'height'=>400,
 'width'=>450,
 'show'=>'fade',
 'hide'=>'fade',
   ),
 ));

    //define the model
  // $model=new Jobs;
 echo 'dialog content here';
 $this->renderPartial('/jobs/view',array('model'=>$data));

 $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

// the link that may open the dialog
 echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
 ));
 ?>

<div class="view">

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_id')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->job_id),array('view','id'=>$data->job_id)); ?>
<br />
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_code')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_code); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_title')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_title); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_desc')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_desc); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_lastdate')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_lastdate); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_photo')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_photo); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_file')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_file); ?>
<br />

<?php /*
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('job_createtime')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->job_createtime); ?>
<br />

*/ ?>

</div>
```

**view.php**

```
 <h1>View Jobs #<?php echo $model->job_id; ?></h1>

 <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'job_id',
    'job_code',
    'job_title',
    'job_desc',
    'job_lastdate',
    'job_photo',
    'job_file',
    'job_createtime',
),
)); ?>
```

**controller actionView()**

```
 public function actionView($id)
 {

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
 }
```

I didn't getting whats wrong in my code.
help me to solve this problem..
Thank You..

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to hit the index.php which will show all the records in a listview. When the id is clicked, you want to show the detail view in a popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your problem there are a couple problems with your widget declaration.

1.Your id is not unique for every ui widget on the screen.
Change `'id' => 'mydialog'` to something like `"dialog_{$data->id}"`. Make sure to change the `onclick` jQuery id to match that id.

2.You have `autoOpen` set to `true`. Set it to `false`.

Also. You're echoing the `'dialog content here'` in every dialog :) .

Cheers

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but its not working. '
  'id'=>'dialog_{$data->id}',
  .
  . ...  
  $this->renderPartial('/jobs/view',array('model'=>$data));

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
    
// the link that may open the dialog
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#dialog_{$data->id}").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
?>'

Comment: What's not working? Are you receiving an error? I have it working on my end with that. Compare your code to http://pastebin.com/3Y83BUPK

Oh, and if that's the code you have in your app, you need to enclose 'dialog_{$data->id}' in double quotes; not single quotes.

Comment: Solved,, Thank you so much. but i didn't get the exact meaning of the code `$dialogId = "dialog_{$data->job_id}";` and `'id'=>$dialogId,` , `array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#'. $dialogId .'").dialog("open"); return false;',` But its working

Comment: Setting `$dialogId = "dialog_{$data->job_id}";` means that the id for the html element will be something like `dialog_1`. The next record would be `dialog_2` assuming the jobs table has records with id=1 and the next with id=2. Now, when you use jQuery to select the dialog elements, you can do so as all the dialog elements have a **unique** id. Otherwise, multiple dialogs would be selected with one id.

Comment: Hello.. there is another problem, in **actionIndex()** i have pagination `'pageSize'=>3,` so that when i go to next page it render all records view on to the index page and when clicking on the link **open dialog** nothing happens. whats going wrong?? in the **actionView** contains `if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)` i think that is the problem, so how to prevent this to only take ajax request of only click on **open dialog** link and not from next pagination?? help please